# Remove all occurrences of words

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to remove all occurrences of words in a text. The words are saved in an array.
But instead of removing them, I just get my original text back:

```
var text = "This is just a little test, to check if it works."
var words = ["this", "is", "a", "to", "if", "it"];

for (i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
  text = text.replace(/words[i]/g, "")
}

alert(text); // result should be: just little test, check works.
```

Here is a fiddle: https://fiddle.jshell.net/y07qgooq/

Comment: You don't need loop, this can be done in a single regex. [`text.replace(new RegExp("\\b(" + words.join("|") + ")\\b", "ig"), "")`](https://fiddle.jshell.net/7kvLw62p/)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your code `words[i]` isn't interpreted as javascript language but as regex language, and will only match "wordsi".
You can craft your regex in the following fashion :

```
new RegExp("\\b" + words[i] + "\\b", "g")
```

I added `\b` word boundaries to make sure the removed words are not parts of words.

If you want to match the leading "This" you will also need to add the case-insensitive flag `i` :

```
new RegExp("\\b" + words[i] + "\\b", "gi")
```

---

If you did not have punctuation, it would be more efficient to use the following alternative :

in ES6 :

```
text.split(" ").filter(word => words.indexOf(word) == -1).join(" ");
```

before ES6 :

```
text.split(" ").filter(function(word) { return words.indexOf(word) == -1; }).join(" ");
```

Comment: You don't actually specify the `/` in the constructor of RegExp, and you are missing a concat after `words[i]`. But besides that this is probably the most complete answer

Comment: @CharlesLeaf both fixed, one by OP and one by myself just as you were commenting. Thanks for your feedback !

Comment: Also, the before ES6 solution does not work for the words "test" or "works" since they are followed by punctuation:  https://fiddle.jshell.net/27bd774j/3/

Comment: @RickHitchcock thanks for your feedback, I'll check how to fix all this in a few minutes. I'm afraid I won't be able to fix the regex-less solutions : I could split on `\W` but I wouldn't be able to join back with the same characters.

Comment: It is indeed a tricky problem, and it may require using a callback within `replace()`.

Comment: @RickHitchcock I fixed the regex solution, word boundaries had to be double-escaped. Working fiddle : https://fiddle.jshell.net/27bd774j/4/

Comment: I won't try to fix the regex-less solution, I think this is one of the situations where using regexps is actually best-practice.

Answer (score 2):

You can create [RegExp](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp) with constructor:

```
text = text.replace(new RegExp(words[i], "g"), "");
```

you can also check word boundaries as suggested by @Aaron and ignore case

```
new RegExp("\\b" + words[i] + "\\b ", "gi")
```

Comment: I get `Th  just  ltle test,  check   works.` So even `is` in `This` is removed.

Answer (score 1):

Because you are replacing the actual text `words[i]` with nothing. Instead, you need to use the text to generate a regular expression.

`text = text.replace(new RegExp(words[i], "g"), "")`